# Reliable global-auto-revert-mode on OSX?

Tags: osx, global-auto-revert-mode

On Mac OSX, I have `global-auto-revert-mode` enabled.  Sometimes I see buffers revert after a change on disk.  However, that doesn't always happen, and I have to `revert-buffer` to see changes (for example sometimes that happens when I switch git branches).

I'm not yet sure under what circumstances files are reverting / not reverting for me.

Is there configuration I can change to make this more reliable?  Are there known issues here that perhaps I can contribute fixes for?

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. Otherwise, consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.